# How to add scroll into treeview

Tags: javascript, html, css

i had treeview and i want to add scroll, but it doesn't work.
i added container to use scroll.

```
.container{
  height:*px;
  width: *Px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Treeview in fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/allengosta/cn962tah/9/

in browser it looks like that:

[trewiew without scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4sSS.png)

Comment: scroll will appear if there's overflow in your container, but since you put `height:*px;` there will be no overflow because the height keeps adjusting. try change it to value such as `200px` it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append container first, than your tree-view. So at the bottom you should put:

```
document.body.appendChild(cont);
cont.appendChild(tw.root);
```

For container I used `height: 80vh;` (80% viewport height), but you can use any height you like.

Updated [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/czjuk04m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To scroll you have to put an exact height to the container so that the content overflows and you can scroll, try with `max-height` property